# Pointer dereferencing from a (char *) to (int * ) not understood in this example

Tags: c, pointers, types

I was taking practice tests on C on a website , where i happened to see this question.
My Doubt is explained in comments , so please read them.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4};  // its assumed to be stored in little-endian i.e;
                             // 2 = 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000
                             // 3 = 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000
                             // 4 = 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000   

    char *p;

    p = arr;

    p = (char*)((int*)(p));  

    printf("%d ", *p);   

    p = (int*)(p+1);       // This casting is expected to convert char pointer p 
                           // to an int pointer , thus value at p ,now is assumed 
                           // to be equal to 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011 
                           // but, the output was : 0  . As ,per my assumption it
                           // should be : 2^24+2^25 = 50331648 ,Please Clarify 
                           // if my assumption is Wrong and explain Why?

    printf("%d\n", *p);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: After `p = (int*)(p+1);` 
Now **`p` is pointing to** __00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011__ (**an integer value** ) because of type conversion `(int *)`,

but `p` still remains a char pointer.

When you print the value at `p`(i.e; the first byte(which is 00000000) of value where `p` is now pointing to (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011),since `p` is still a char pointer;the value at `p` i.e; `*p` is a char value(1 byte)), you are printing the value  0.

Answer (score 2):

If you would cast `p` back to `int*`, then the `int` value would be:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011
```

where the last byte is the first byte of your second array element. By doing `p+1`, you're skipping the least signigicant byte of the first element.

Remember that `p` remains a char pointer, so assigning an `int*` to it will not change it's type.

When you `printf` the char at `p+1`, you are printing the value of the second byte, which is 0.

Comment: what if the endianess is big endiance?

Answer (score 1):

Remember `p` is still a `char`-pointer. So `*p` fetches a `char` value from it. The `char` value is then promoted to an `int` when passed as an argument to a variadic function (like `printf`).

Answer (score 1):

```
p = (char*)((int*)(p));
// till now the pointer p is type casted to store the variable of type character.

printf("%d, ", *p); // %d means integer value so value at first address i.e. 2 will be printed.

p = (int*)(p+1); // here p is still of type character as type casted in step 1 so p(i.e address) and plus 1 will increase only by one byte so
```

Assuming that integer requires 2 bytes of storage
the integer array will be stored in memory as

```
value 2 3 4
address 00000010 00000000 00000011 00000000 00000100 00000000 
pointer p+1
```

so `p+1` points to that location which is unfilled as during intialization 2,3,4 were stored in variable of type integer(2 bytes).

so `p+1` will point to `00000000`.

`(int*)p+1 // p+1 is type casted again to integer`

`printf("%d", *p); // this will print 0 as output as by default integer contains 0 as value.`

Comment: but after `p= (int *)(p+1);` p should be an integer pointer , so the value at p i.e; *p is now :00000000 00000011 which is equal to 2^8+2^9 isn't it?

Comment: @EF No, `p+1` will points to that location which is unfilled(next to 4) i.e. it will point to `00000000`

Comment: the value next to 4 should be a garbage value , because we are using local variables which are in stack . How can that be 00000000