# c char to int pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)    
{
    int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4};
    char *p;
    p = (char*)arr;
    printf("%d", *(int*)(p+1));
    return 0;
}
```

I was doing this question on pointer. I expected output to be some garbage value since casting from char* to int* but the output always comes out to be 50331648 which is strange. Please explain

EDIT: I read this output problem on some website so need output according to given instructions

Comment: P is char* and arr is int.

Comment: @user2653926, Yes, its a problem as `(p + 1)` can be misaligned for an `int *`

Comment: does this compile ? you can't assign address of `int` to a char pointer.

Comment: @machine_1 NO :)), because of **assignment from incompatible pointer type**

Comment: What do you want explained? You are invoking undefined behavior, and this is what you get. Check memory dump of your array if you want "under the hood" kind of explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer dereferencing from a (char \*) to (int \* ) not understood in this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963679/pointer-dereferencing-from-a-char-to-int-not-understood-in-this-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared arr as int and *p as char*. Your program will not compile using a modern compiler. 
What you try there is to assign different types of pointers which is wrong with that approach.

I think this is what you need:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)    {
    int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4};
    char *p;
    p = (char*)arr;
    printf("%d", *(int*)(p+1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output (garbage):

> 50331648

Answer (score 7):

What you are doing is undefined behavior.

Assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4

**Little endian system**

In a little endian system, the memory layout for `arr` is:

```
arr
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 02 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 03 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 04 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

When you use:

```
char* p = arr;

p    p+1
|    |
v    v
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 02 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 03 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 04 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

If you interpret `p+1` as an `int*`, and evaluate the object at that location as an `int`, you get:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 00 | 00 | 00 | 03 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

In a little endian system, that number is

```
0x03000000
```

which is equal to `50331648`, which is the output you get.

**Big endian system**

In a big endian system, the memory layout for `arr` is:

```
arr
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 00 | 00 | 00 | 02 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 03 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 04 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

the number you will get when evaluating `*(int*)(p+1)` is:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 00 | 00 | 02 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

That is equal to `0x0200`, i.e. 512.

It should be obvious why the operation you are performing is undefined behavior.

Comment: Or you can get a [bus error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error) due to an unaligned access.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a line by line explanation of your code and finally explain why you're getting that output

```
//assuming 32-bit machine 
int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4}; //arr is a pointer to the first element which is an int 2 with a memory size of 4 bytes (int = 4 bytes)
char *p; //p is declared a pointer to a char implying it points to a 1 byte memory size (char = 1 byte)
p = (char*)arr; /* p now points to the first element of the array but actually this happens by luck. 
                  here is why: (char*)arr will attempt to cast the int pointer to a char pointer, 
                  in other words, asking it to present whatever took 4bytes to be presented in 1 byte 
                  which will overwrite the least significant bytes. but since numbers are stored in reverse order, 
                  it will overwrite only zeros causing no problem.*/
printf("%d", *(int*)(p+1)); /* p is still a char pointer holding memory address of 2 in the array. 
                            casting that to int* will add extra bytes from memory. so finally what you're getting is 
                            garbage number which I think is the virtual memory limit, (48 Gb *1024 *1024 = 50331648 Kb)*/
```